# get_results() query not working only when entering strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to send a query to a database, WHERE works fine if I'm querying for a number but not for a string. Example, if I try:

```
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_11_posts WHERE ID = 30', OBJECT); I get a result, no problem
```

However when I try a string, eg

```
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_11_posts WHERE post_title = Office Home', OBJECT);
```

it doesn't return anything, wonder if anyone can spot the reason why? column name is correct and the value does exist in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use quotes around some data types in SQL, integers being one of those types. That is why the first block of code works. It is a perfectly valid SQL statement.

You do need to quote strings in SQL. That is why your second block of code does not work. The correct form would be:

```
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results(
  'SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_11_posts WHERE post_title = "Office Home"',   
  OBJECT
);
```

If your data is in any way subject to user input you should use `prepare()`.

```
$string = "Office Home"; // if coming from $_POST or $_GET data or other user manipulatable sources
$sql = 'SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_11_posts WHERE post_title = %s';
$sql = $wpdb->prepare($sql,$string);
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results($sql,OBJECT);
```

`prepare()` will add the quotes as needed based on the data type indicated by the placeholder-- `%s`.

Answer (score -1):

Answer for: ***it doesn't return anything, wonder if anyone can spot the reason why?***

MySQL is a lot like PHP, and will auto-convert data types as best it can. Since you're working with an int field (left-hand side), it'll try to transparently convert the right-hand-side of the argument into an int as well, so '9' just becomes 9.

Strictly speaking, the quotes are unnecessary, and force MySQL to do a typecasting/conversion, so it wastes a bit of CPU time. In practice, unless you're running a Google-sized operation, such conversion overhead is going to be microscopically small.

I changes your query code as per requirement. Please check it.

```
$strTitle = "Office Home";
$all_pages = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT post_title, guid FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title = "'. $strTitle .'"', OBJECT);
```

Let me know if there is any query/doubt from this.

Comment: You say quotes are unnecessary, but your solution is to use quotes - can you clarify to OP that the issue is you *need* quotes for non-integer/float `WHERE` values - otherwise I think it's a little confusing.

Comment: I would request you to review my full comment. What I was trying to explain was Since you're working with an int field (left-hand side), it'll try to transparently convert the right-hand-side of the argument into an int as well, so '9' just becomes 9.

Comment: Sure thing, but that's not the issue here, is it? OP specifically says `post_title = Office Home` doesn't work - reason why? No quotes.

Comment: Saying that quotes don't matter in SQL is extremely misleading to the point of being a bit absurd. Quotes absolutely do matter in SQL, though sometimes they are necessary and sometimes not necessary and sometimes not using quotes is the correct thing to do. In all cases, quotes do matter.